# SceneManager.LoadScene works fine when testing in Unity, but not when deploying to the Oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

I'm trying to change to a different scene. To test it I've just added a change scene script to an empty object that will trigger the moment the scene is loaded.

**Here is the script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start () {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I run it in Unity, it instantly loads the scene I want it to. However, when I deploy it onto the Oculus Quest, absolutely nothing happens. It just stays in the current scene. I've tried using LoadScene and LoadSceneAsync but it just isn't working. 
Any idea why this is?

Comment: Is your scene in the build settings?

Comment: Yeah it definitely is. It works perfectly when clicking the play button in Unity.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I've posted an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The issue seems to be with the OVR Quick Preview even if I deploy the full build. It only works when I actually deploy it properly from the Build Settings.